# When does $x^{x+1}= (x+1)^x$?

Tags: logarithms, problem-solving

After seeing the problem of which is bigger out of $9^{10}$ or $10^9$ (and eventually working out a few ways to answer that) I got interested in where it switches. I.e.

$2^3$ < $3^2$

But:

$3^4$ > $4^3$

So, $x^{(x+1)}$ = $({x+1})^x$ must be a value for $x$ between $2$ and $3$. Naturally I guessed $e$, but that is too high.

I've tried taking logs of each side, to either base $x$ or base $x+1$ but I keep ending up stuck. E.g. $x+1 = x \log_x(x+1)$ and the only thing I know to do with $\log(a + b)$ is turn it into a $\log(a) + \log(1 + b/a)$, which doesn't get me anywhere.

So, being a pragmatic guy, I plotted $x^{x+1}-({x+1})^x$, and started thrashing around trying to find an equation to match where it crosses the $x$-axis. This is *really* close - slightly too large (2.29316638129); change the $7$ to $8$ and it is slightly too small ($2.29316607539$):

$$x=e-\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{e^3}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{e^5}\right)-\left(\frac{2}{e^8}\right)-\left(\frac{2}{e^{11}}\right)-\left(\frac{2}{e^{13}}\right)-\left(\frac{7}{e^{15}}\right)$$

But this stinks of over-fitting, doesn't it. :-)

Comment: It's better to write $(1+\frac{1}{x})^x=x$ to see why $2<x<e$ . To get the solution for $x$ you can use the iteration $x_{n+1}=(1+\frac{1}{x_n})^{x_n}$ with e.g. $x_0:=2$ .

Comment: Interesting fact: This constant is approximately equal to $4\gamma$ (within 1% of accuracy, with $\gamma$ being the Euler-Mascheroni constant).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are playing with an old toy :)

The constant you are looking for is called **Foias-Ewing constant** and the exact value is:

[image]

You can find more about this number and its properties here:

- [OEIS sequence A085846](http://oeis.org/A085846)
- [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FoiasConstant.html)

Honestly I did not know anything about this number 5 minutes ago. I just Googled a few starting digits of your number and... voila! :)

Comment: There's a constant for everything ! ;-)

Comment: @YvesDaoust Just take a look at this: http://www.ebyte.it/library/educards/constants/MathConstants.html :)

Comment: The Ultimate Adams constant seems to be missing. :-(

Comment: @YvesDaoust Actually, it's there, but disguised as a Catalan number :)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a formula to calculate it, or can it only be calculated with numeric methods? (I'm going to be a bit disappointed if my failure to solve the equations isn't simply due to my ignorance.)

Comment: The constant is the limit of the sequence $a_{n+1}=(1+\frac{1}{a_n})^{a_n}$, with $a_1=1$. I could not find anything more elegant.

Comment: Computers are much faster nowadays. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=What+is+the+sixth+Catalan+number+%3F